# Set AWS Cloudwatch Alarm datapoint timespan and action to shut it down

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

Follwing case:
We want an Alarm in AWS that reads the EstimatedCharges Metric of AmazonCloudWatch every 5 minutes (for potential log overflow). But the only timespan I can set are 6 hours, else it gives me "Insufficient" as Status. How can I change the metric so that I can use it with 5 minutes between each check?

And how can I make an action that will stop the Cloudwatch Logs when over X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation.

> CloudWatch Billing metrics are updated every 6 hours.

Thus, your Alert may change the status only every 6 hours.

Comment: Oh, thanks. So I can't change the metric itself to every 5 minutes or create a custom metric with the same attribute?
And what about the action to shut it down or restrict logs when its over X$?

Comment: I think you cannot. The similar situation is with 
S3 -> NumberOfObjects, this metric is recalculated only every 24 hours.

Comment: as for actions:
You may map you Alarm to SNS(Simple Notification Service), and notify through SNS that something goes wrong. So, SNS may send an e-mail/sms/etc or call the lambda function, which may switch off the most pricey service

Answer (score 0):

Just set **Treat Missing Data** to **notBreaching**

notBreaching – Missing data points are treated as "good" and within the threshold,

More info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html

Comment: Then it shows as "good", but still doesn't scan the EstimatedCharges every 5 minutes like I set in Period, which was my goal.